# How to convert HEX color to smali color (in Java)?

Tags: java, android, colors, hex, smali

How to convert color value in HEX to smali color (and back)? For example: `#ff212121` (hex) -> `-0xdededf` (smali). #`df3192b8` -> `-0x20ce6d48` etc.

Comment: http://touchwizreborn.blogspot.com/2016/02/how-to-convert-hex-color-code-to-smali.html

Comment: It was easier than I thought. It is strange that I don't found this link when searching in Google. Thank you!

Comment: That link is incorrect. You'll end up with a color that is off-by-one from the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to convert anything. If your hex code is `#df3192b8`, then you can use `0xdf3192b8`.

32-bit integer constants in smali can be specified with a value between `-2^31` and `2^32-1` (not `2^31-1`). Basically, it's a combination of the possible signed and unsigned 32-bit values.

Of course, since java only has signed integers, when you specify a value in the range of `2^31` - `2^32 - 1`, it gets interpreted by the virtual machine as a negative number, and this is the default representation that baksmali uses when disassembling a class. This is why you see values like `-0x20ce6d48` instead of `0xdf3192b8` in the disassembly. But both values generate the same bytecode/specify the same color.

In order to "convert back", if the value is positive, then there's no need to do anything. If the value is negative, simply add `0x100000000` to the value. e.g. `-0x20ce6d48 + 0x100000000 = 0xdf3192b8`, so a value of `-0x20ce6d48` corresponds to a hex color code of `#df3192b8`.

Answer (score -1):

1. Do a hexadecimal subtraction of all your digits in your color from 'f'
2. pre- append -0x in front of your new hexadecimal number.

Comment: There's no need to convert the hex color code to its signed representation. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Also, what you describe is one's complement, but signed integers use a two's complement representation, so your conversion is off by one.